# Conditional formatting with color coding in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to do something similar to Conditional formatting with color as in excel using R. I have a dataset with 0,1,2,3 as their values.

```
Opp <- c(10968788,11046809,11086342,11097787,11126732,11145638,11163014,11163034,11165910,11167232)
A <- c(1,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2)
B <- c(1,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2)
C <- c(1,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,0)
D <- c(2,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3)
E <- c(2,2,3,3,3,3,3,0,3,0)
df <- data.frame(Opp,A,B,C,D,E)
```

Input
[image]

Expected Output
[image]

I tried to get the output using a heatmap but was not successful. Please help

Comment: On the R console? In RStudio? In a rendered report? In an exported xlsx document? *Where* are you hoping to render/display this?

Comment: I am trying to do this in rstudio. I will use the output in my PPT. Thank you

Comment: You didn't really answer the question, since "RStudio" has at least three panes where one might want to see data presented, but I think I get the point. Since you say you want it in powerpoint, that suggests you can use [`heatmap`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/heatmap.html) to plot your data for you, or perhaps [`ggplot2::geom_bin_2d`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bin_2d.html) or [`ggplot2::geom_hex`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Opp) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), factor)) %>% 
    ggplot() +
        aes(name, Opp, fill = value) + 
        geom_tile()
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i am expecting, I was looking to make 1 as red, 2 as Yellow 3 as green, and 0 as white. If you can help me with the color selection.

Comment: df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Opp) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), factor)) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(name, Opp, fill = value) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "yellow", "green"))